# Importing into meilisearch from mongodb using laravel scout takes too long

Tags: mongodb, laravel-8, laravel-scout, meilisearch, laravel-mongodb

I have around 6 million rows in my mongodb collection and importing into meilisearch using `php artisan scout:import 'model'` takes forever to finish. 
Importing data with limit option `php artisan scout:import 'model' -c 10000` gives me the following error.

> MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException
> Expected "limit" option to have type "integer" but found "string"
> at vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php:59
> 55▕
> 56▕             $expectedType = $typeString;
> 57▕         }
> 58▕
> ➜  59▕         return new static(sprintf('Expected %s to have type "%s" but found >"%s"', $name, $expectedType, get_debug_type($value)));
> 60▕     }
> 61▕ }
> 62▕
>
> +27 vendor frames
> 28  artisan:37
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()

I also tried exporting the collection as json from mongodb and manual importing into meilisearch using `curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:7700/indexs/posts/documents' / --data @/data/posts.json` gives the following error.

> {"message":"Invalid JSON: invalid type: map, expected a sequence at line 1 column 0","errorCode":"bad_request","errorType":"invalid_request_error","errorLink":"https://docs.meilisearch.com/errors#bad_request"}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
> Posts.json is the exported json file of mongodb collection using `mongoexport` command.

How can I import data fast into meilisearch?

**Versions**

- "laravel/scout":"^9.1"
- "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
- "meilisearch/meilisearch-php": "^0.18.2",
- mongodb version : "3.6"

**OS**

- Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Did you do you `mongoexport` with the --jsonArray` flag? If not that might help. I don't know lavavel scout so there very well may be a better option that lets you do it directly without curl, but hopefully this helps at lets get started with the curl option.

Comment: @paul41 I did `mongoexport` with `--jsonArray` flag but when I inspect the json file, there is "_id" field and the field has another attribute `$oid` assigned to value like `{"_id":{"$oid":'1234568'}}`. There must be primary field which is **default** `id` field to import into meilisearch.

Comment: @paul41 I can't set nested attribute "$oid" as primary key in meilisearch. I run the following command `curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:7700/indexes" --data '{"uid":"posts","primaryKey":"_id.$oid"}'` but it didn't work. There is no document inside posts index in meilisearch.

Comment: The `id` field can't be nested in MeiliSearch and I don't think there is a way to have `mongoexport` not include the `oid` nesting since that is specifying it is an object id. The two options I can think of are to use a program to un-nest the `_id` field after export, or if there is another unique field in the document you could tell MeiliSearch to use that field instead.

Comment: @paul41 using another unique field as primary key works! Thank you :)